# delete .ssh directory in root/.ssh/

Tags: linux, ssh

I try to practice to use ssh keygen to generate public key and private key

And then I type `cd .ssh`

And it said there is no directory.

Then I found that I do it wrong. I use superuser to  generate the key
so it create the directory '/root/.ssh/'

Please help me to delete the .ssh directory in the root 
Thank you.

Comment: As in, the unix command to delete a folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to log in as the superuser and delete the folder, or just use the sudo command.

```
sudo su
rm -rf /root/.ssh
```

or

```
sudo rm -rf /root/.ssh
```

Unless you cannot log into your superaccount, then thats a different story.

Comment: thanks for helping me.I was so nervers at that moment